# How to fix - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' for web scraping?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` error when I run the below code:

```
!pip install requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
url= 'https://www.amazon.com/iHealth-Thermometer-Vibration-Notification-Thermopile/dp/B075QQ8VZW/ref=lp_16225005011_1_2'
headers=("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
page = requests.get(url,headers= headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

the user agent in the header is the dictionary. review the below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
url= 'https://www.amazon.com/iHealth-Thermometer-Vibration-Notification-Thermopile/dp/B075QQ8VZW/ref=lp_16225005011_1_2'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
page = requests.get(url,headers= headers)
```

pls note, amazon is good at finding bot requests, so it's not easy to get the page content through requests.